# making specific values into a new sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am a very basic excel user so I will explain this the best way I can.
I have an excel sheet we are using to keep track of patients for switching to a concierge practice. When they say no I make the font of their row red (each patient has a row with multiple columns for their info, like last name, first name, address, etc). If yes, I make it green, yellow=maybe, black =dead, purple=scholarship. I also have a column in front of their name that says a yes, no, maybe, scholarship, or dead as I have a formula at the bottom tallying each response. 
What the Dr wants now is for each yes, no, maybe, scholarship, etc to get their own sheet with a formula. So if I write a yes next to their name they will end up on a new sheet all for yes's. If they say no they will end up on a new sheet that is for no's. Is this possible? And if so can someone give me a formula?
Thank you

Comment: I know you asked for a formula, but a manual (and maybe more understandable) way of doing it would be to filter on the description column (or just filter by color on the colored column). Then copy and paste to the new sheet.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**

One of the easiest ways without VBA to do this is to add 3 "helper columns" (which you can even hide after written) next to your data like shown:

[image]

**Inserting helper columns**

These helper columns put an index number if the value is equal to their row's value, incrementing the number every time it is found. So for example, in my example shown, I put cell C2 =

```
=IF(A2="yes",MAX($C$1:C1)+1,"")
```

Cell D2 =

```
=IF(A2="no",MAX($D$1:D1)+1,"")
```

and so forth. Dragging down produces the index numbers.

**Gathering data in new sheets**

Now in the separate sheets it becomes much simpler to retrieve each set of data.

So if sheet2 represents all yes's then in sheet2, I would use a match and index function.  So cell A2 in sheet2 would be:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(ROW(A2)-1,Sheet1!C:C,0))
```

[image]

**How this works**

The MATCH(ROW(A2)-1,Sheet1!C:C,0) part is using the current row value as the number to look up and C:C is my "yes helper column" in sheet1. When dragging this down, the ROW(A2) becomes ROW(A3), then ROW(A4), and so forth. The 0 inside the MATCH indicates it is looking for an exact match.

The INDEX() part simply looks up a column based on the MATCH value. In my case I looked up column B to retrieve my data from. You could do something similar for this for each column you want to copy to the new sheet, changing B to whichever row you are retrieving from.